# Regarding my screenshot are my GPUs or CPus running?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, deep-learning, gpu

I am running a Tensorflow Deep Learning model on Ubuntu 18.04. I have Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Ti. I also have CUDA installed.

I am confused whether the current run is using my 8 core CPUs or my GPUs, or both. I am not sure if my GPUs are being used.

Can you explain what exactly is going on regarding my screenshots that I took at the same time while running on a notebook?

For CPU:

[image]

For GPU with $ nvidia-smi -l

[image]

For GPU with $ nvidia-smi dmon

[image]

Comment: yes, your gpu is being used.  the nvidia-smi output that shows .../deepchem/bin/python using ~10GB of memory, and the 19% GPU utilization indicate that your GPU is being used.

Comment: I also have 8 of my CPU cores running, which makes me think if only CPUs are used. Also, $ nvidia-smi dmon results show mem as 1 % and it seems like no GPU is used regarding that.

Comment: A program like tensorflow, even if it "using" the GPU, is also using the CPU.  In fact this statement is true for any program that "uses" the GPU.

Comment: Sure, but instead of one CPU, all the 8 cores are being used at the same time at similar levels, which made me confused whether CPU or GPU is running.

Comment: People get confused because they have a misconception, the CPU will **always** be used for something, you cannot run python code only in the GPU. So it is either CPU or CPU + GPU.